# Canon EOS 1100D Movie recording and manual modes are not working but auto modes are working fine

Tags: canon, manual-mode, canon-1100d, movie

I have a Canon EOS 1100D with Class 10 32GB memory card.
Everything was working fine, like auto modes and manual modes.

After few weeks I switched on my camera to shoot a movie but ***camera is not recording anything.***

Also on switching to the manual modes like P, TV, AV, M, A-DEP. **LCD screen goes black nothing is shown and Menu button is not responding**.

For auto modes like Full Auto, Flash off, Creative Auto, Sports, etc., **I am able to capture the photo successfully** but message `"This function is not selectable in the current shooting mode"` is displayed on LCD screen.

I have tried everything mentioned in user manual
https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/1/0300004731/02/eosrt3-eos1100d-bim2-c-en.pdf and https://in.canon/en/support/8201012700

Nothing helped.

What can be the issue?
Any troubleshooting points that I can try will be helpful.

Comment: Several answers [here](https://community.usa.canon.com/t5/EOS-Rebel/this-function-is-not-selectable-in-the-current-shooting-mode/td-p/151953/page/2) hint that it could be a button stuck in depressed position.

Comment: @xenoid, thank you for pointing to [this](https://community.usa.canon.com/t5/EOS-Rebel/this-function-is-not-selectable-in-the-current-shooting-mode/td-p/151953/page/2) link, I read all the conversation, looks like I too will have to visit Canon Service Center. The problem mentioned in link and my issue both are same.